# Parse error while selecting Double column in Apache Flink SQL

Tags: java, apache-flink, import-from-csv

I've imported data from a CSV file into Apache Flink Java using the TableSource class and registered the table as u can see in the big code sample entirely below. When I print the datatype of the HBATable I get the following output:

`|-- measurementID: INT`
`|-- dateTime: TIMESTAMP(3)`
`|-- result: DOUBLE`
`|-- unixDateTime: BIGINT`

The problem is when I try to perform a simple SQL query on the HBATable I get a parseError on the `Result` column. U can see the simple SQL query below and the error message.

`Table t = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT result FROM HBATable " );`

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "result" at line 1, column 8

```
        BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = BatchTableEnvironment.create(fbEnv);

        TableSource csvSource = CsvTableSource.builder()
                .path("path")
                .fieldDelimiter(";")
                .field("ID", Types.INT())
                .field("dateTime", Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP())
                .field("result", Types.DOUBLE())
                .field("unixDateTime", Types.LONG())
                .build();

        //Register the TableSource as table "HTable"
        tableEnv.registerTableSource("HTable", csvSource);
        Table HBATable = tableEnv.scan("HTable");
        tableEnv.registerTable("HBATable", HBATable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` is a [reserved keyword](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql.html#reserved-keywords). Try renaming that field.